# Kivy Changing screens with buttons python code

Tags: python, kivy

I keep getting this error

TypeError: `__init__()` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I tried everything to make it work but it still seems not to work. I'm trying to make an button where you click it if makes you go to a different screen but in python code.

```
self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=('Image.png'), size=(200,200), size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), on_press=ScreenFive, pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You sent `ScreenFive` as callback for **on_press**. the *callback* is called with the button instance so your error raise.

try this:

```
def callback(instance):
    sm.current = "screen_five"

... ... on_press=callback
```

Comment: NameError: name 'sm' is not defined

Comment: @AdamKamil - its a ScreenManager, change it to fit your code

Comment: `def callback(instance):
    scene=ScreenManager()
    scene.current = "OpeningScreen"
    print("Work?!")`
-                                                     
`self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=('image.png'), size=(200,200), size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), on_press=callback, pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))`

Comment: You are using not using `ScreenManager` correctly, you should create it only once

Comment: What do you mean by creating only once?

Comment: def build(): global sm; sm = ScreenManager()

Comment: I've done that and it says that there is no screen called "Screen_Five"

Comment: please provide a full small example.

Comment: kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "Screen_Five".

Comment: I put the 'sm' inside the def build and I get this error now. I dont know why but I have that screen in my code.